IEEE754 Floating point conversion
can someone help with the following conversion?
I have this data -eight ASCII character representation of a binary floating point, units are in percent 0 to +100.000% or -100.000% to +100.000%:
81CCB780
FADA7000
05BFFFFC
06B40000
F1A00000
79A14000
79D1B000
799F1000
78AB4000

Question: how can we get decimal percents back from this data?

Although these look like IEEE754 singles, they can't be.  The exponents are all wrong.  http://timr.4roberts.us/paste/?QlpoOTFBWSZTWeMlWkwAAHJZAGAQQAt/4D8AMADaNDVPJo9JiKPUMg1R6YT0U0A0DNVGj1A0HqMkXKpBU7zo18RdPYYuXJrPmOik4GnFK2FZmfsyOw8fRrJiyb67T8+BR3qLKp8fN54EbaV1eMeNaeMPSdJjk3N7n4KoOqqJWstzI6gzlKiDhaKSWfGy95wtmBvAc1XItS6ImoShvPwDTlYaDDoaqZBsGEWcI4VQN769P2vBzWUYvdJ0xkJDbCjn8XckU4UJDjJVpMA=
